# Detect direct access to header

Tags: php, http-headers

I have these 2 scripts:

login.php:

```
   if ( checkLogin( $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'] ) ) { 
        header('location:example.php?message=11');
        die(); 
   } else {
        header('location:example.php?message=10');
        die();
   }
```

and example.php

```
if( isset($_GET['message']) )
{
    if($_GET['message']==10) 
    {
      // do something
    }
}
```

Now I need a way to check people copying and pasting the URI *www.mysite.com/**example.php?message=11*** and so having direct access to *example.php* without passing through *login.php*.

In other words, is there a way to check in *example.php* script that I'm coming from *login.php* and that the user did not directly paste the URI *www.mysite.com/**example.php?message=11***?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In example.php add to the top :

```
include_once('login.php');
```

But you'll have to remove the header location in login.php, with a cookie of data login.